# Why is my car battery charger not powering on?

Tags: battery, car, battery-charger

I've had my car battery charger for about six months and, just recently, it won't power on.  When I connect it to the battery and the mains, the orange light comes on but there is no low humming noise that means its charging.  Usually when it was working, I connect it to the battery and the mains, the light orange light comes on and the unit hums because its powered on.  Now the orange light comes on and stays on but there is no power sound.  Can anyone help?

Comment: What type of battery?

Answer (score 0):

most probably, your charger has a blown fuse. replace the fuse with a known good one. use multimeter and safely check for the voltage across output, i.e. +ve and -ve connectors of your charger.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I thought it could be the fuse,  but the orange light does come on when I connect the charger to the battery and the mains.  But I can't hear anything that says the battery charger is powered.  If the fuse has blown, would the orange light still come on when the charger is connected to the battery and the mains?

Comment: please send the pics.

Comment: please upload video or gif !!

Comment: I'm not sure how useful an image or video will be as it will only show the battery charger connected to the battery and mains with the orange light on.  I really need to know whether the orange light will come on even if the fuse needs to be replaced?

Comment: check the output voltage.